# Images for AlertDialog buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, controls

Is it possible to add drawables to the *positive*, *negative* and *neutral* buttons of an AlertDialog? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `onPrepareDialog` is deprecated, you can use the `onShowListener` instead.

Also you should set the Drawable bounds or it will be placed far left.

Output of Code below

[image: Output of Code below]

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("My Dialog")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("Play", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                }).create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                // if you do the following it will be left aligned, doesn't look
                // correct
                // button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play,
                // 0, 0, 0);

                Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                        android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                // set the bounds to place the drawable a bit right
                drawable.setBounds((int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
                        0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1.5),
                        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);

                // could modify the placement more here if desired
                // button.setCompoundDrawablePadding();
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I want to show icon closer to play text. so can you please suggest me?

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to use your code? How to instantiate the Dialog?

Answer (score 8):

After you have built the `AlertDialog` in `onCreateDialog` you can use the following code in `onPrepareDialog` to add an image to the positive button:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog)dialog;
    Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.icon), null, null, null);

}
```

Trying to add the drawable to the button in the `onCreateDialog` method does not seem to work.

Comment: Will try and get back to this Frank.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by getting a reference to the button using the getButton() method:

```
alert.show();
Button email = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
email.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.email);
```

Note that you must use the getButton() AFTER calling the show() method, otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException..

Comment: Will check and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add buttons in the onCreateDialog and MUST do it in the onPrepareDialog because AlertDialog are handled in a very special way by android :

you actually don't really hold a reference to the real dialog when you use alert dialog, the object you get by using AlertDialog.Builder.create() is just a face to an inner controller.

And before create is actually called, there is no such controller in the jvm. Just the facade. So, until this method is called (at the end of onCreateDialog if you let your activity manage its own dialogs), the real controller doesn't exist, and real buttons don't neither.

brand new SOF commenter, Stéphane

Answer (score 2):

As @aaronvargas said, use `onShowListener`. I will improve his answer a little bit, since for older/smaller devices the image overlaps the text. Here is the `onShow` code:

```
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
    Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.your_img, 0, 0, 0);
    Utils.centerImageAndTextInButton(button);
}
```

Here is an utility function to center a left image and text inside a `Button`:

```
public static void centerImageAndTextInButton(Button button) {
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    //Get text bounds
    CharSequence text = button.getText();
    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        TextPaint textPaint = button.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text.toString(), 0, text.length(), textBounds);
    }
    //Set left drawable bounds
    Drawable leftDrawable = button.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
    if (leftDrawable != null) {
        Rect leftBounds = leftDrawable.copyBounds();
        int width = button.getWidth() - (button.getPaddingLeft() + button.getPaddingRight());
        int leftOffset = (width - (textBounds.width() + leftBounds.width()) - button.getCompoundDrawablePadding()) / 2 - button.getCompoundDrawablePadding();
        leftBounds.offset(leftOffset, 0);
        leftDrawable.setBounds(leftBounds);
    }
}
```

This last function uses the width of the `Button` to make the calculation, so you **must** check that you are calling this in the right place. That is, the width should be other than zero. In this case, calling it from `onShow` **is** the right place :).

Answer (score 1):

1.first create a new layout file to store the imagebuttons：new_layout.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background = "#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- game button -->
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/game"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background = "#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/game"/>

    <!-- browser button -->
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/browser"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background = "#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/browser"/>

   <!-- email button -->
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background = "#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/email"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2.add the code below to where you want the dialogue to show:

```
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TalkerActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.show();
    Window win = alertDialog.getWindow();
    win.setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

    //Game
    ImageButton game_btn = (ImageButton)win.findViewById(R.id.game);
    game_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    //Browser
    ImageButton browser_btn = (ImageButton)win.findViewById(R.id.browser);
    browser_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    //Email
    ImageButton email_btn = (ImageButton)win.findViewById(R.id.email);
    email_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

link:http://blog.csdn.net/willproud/article/details/9191971