# setNegativeButton with icon image Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using the following code to close an Alert Dialog:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); */

                if ( result.equals("0") ){

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
                    alert.setTitle("Patrocinador");

                    alert.setMessage("Lo sentimos");

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();





                }

}
```

The problem is that I would like to replace the text "Close" for icon png

How could I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Use a `Dialog` or a `DialogFragment` to make you own layout. This would easily solve your problem.

Comment: repleace to a image .png

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830973/3168859)..Please ping me if that helped you..

Comment: check my edit, with the code complete. Helpme please...

Comment: did you try the solutions specified in the above said link??

Comment: i'm trying but i don't understand very well. I'm new in this