# Android Studio - Set icon and change font colour

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app I have added code to allow the user to either select an image from the gallery or take a photo using the camera. This happens when the camera icon is selected at the top right corner, and a dialog box appears with both those options. I am just wondering how i would add an icon which would be used as buttons. So for example when the dialog box appears i want an image of the android gallery icon that when selected takes you into the gallery. Also want the text 'Gallery' in a different font colour.

Here is the code used to create the options

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_voip_call) {
        Utils.startCall(this, contact);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_camera) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Pick Image from")
                .setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //camera intent
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
                        startActivity(cameraIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do you want to show your own icon for gallery along with the font in the gallery screen ?

Comment: Yeah i want show own icon, currently as it stands in order to get into the gallery... you select the 'Gallery' which is currently just text, in the pop up option box when camera icon is selected. So instead of text, i want my own gallery icon to appear. Thanks

Comment: use onShow event : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830973/1129995

Comment: zaki, he want to make change in anther application (gallery in our case) not in the same application. So Dialog.onShow could change the select button thing but it will not effect other application

Comment: @AttiqurRehman ah I see thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys il see if this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create an activity which will list all images from your gallery (as it is your own activity, you can have any icon or font). Besides that you cann't change default gallery application

Comment: Is this the only way possible to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, It is the only to achieve this But I will suggest you to select a already written Github library to display the Gallery (just make changes according to your font and other requirment) instead of writing whole stuff yourself

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, i am very new to android studio and programming. Sorry

Comment: Just google the keyword " list of all images from gallery in android", I am pretty much sure you will get much help

Answer (score 0):

Here is partial code to select the image from gallery or take it with the help of camera...

You can see the full code at https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context){
    Intent chooserIntent = null;
    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);
    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }
    return chooserIntent;
}
private static List<Intent> addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
        targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        list.add(targetedIntent);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below given lines before `AlertDialog alert = builder.create();`

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

            button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.your_gallery_resource,


            Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                    android.R.drawable.your_gallery_resource);

            // set the bounds to place the drawable a bit right
            drawable.setBounds((int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
                    0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1.5),
                    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);

            // could modify the placement more here if desired
            // button.setCompoundDrawablePadding();
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:** The above code is only for gallery button, do it in a similar way for camera button.